# How to send a pull request to a forked repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

i'm new to github (just moved from svn) and faced following issue.

1. There's a main git repo named A.(There are lots of Head developers sending PRs to this repo)
2. Head developer B forked repo A. His forked repo is named C.(There are lots of developers sending PRs to this repo as well)
3. Developer1 forked from A.
4. Developer2 forked from head developer's repo C.

After a while, developer1 have to send a Pull Request to head developer's repo (C) including all the changes done by developer2.

In this scenario i'm the developer1 :) . and so far i got all the changes done by developer2 without a issue. But I can not rebase with C since i forked the parent git repo A.

I can not even fork C since i have already forked A(parent of C). Can someone please tell me how to send a Pull Request to C correctly in this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add the repo you're trying to contribute to as an upstream master and pull that first before pushing back your pull request.
- [Config a remote for a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/) ..and then.. 
- [Sync your fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/)